# Authentication for WebMathematica Apps?

Tags: webmathematica, mathematica-online

Any good ways to implement authentication for WebMathematica apps. I am a novice to JSP and Java servlet technology.

At tomcat level one could implement basic or digest HTTP methods. What I am looking for is implementing web based or token based authentication.